# jQuery Insert external html page <title> into another html page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, frontend

I have two files index.html and index2.html. Both files are in the same directory on a local machine (no access to PHP, etc).

I'm trying to take the

```
<title>Page Title</title>
```

from index.html and insert it into a div.content in index2.html using jQuery. In index2.html I have:

```
$('.content').load("index.html title");
```

I tried using jQuery .load() and it's not working and I see the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/load/) states:

"jQuery uses the browser's .innerHTML property to parse the retrieved document and insert it into the current document. During this process, browsers often filter elements from the document such as <html>, <title>, or <head> elements. As a result, the elements retrieved by .load() may not be exactly the same as if the document were retrieved directly by the browser."

How can I retrieve the title from index.html and to place it in div.content in index2.html using jQuery?

Comment: Are there any errors is your console? Is the `.load()` method actually retrieving the page?

Comment: No errors in the console, and I was able to load other parts of the index.html into index2.html like `$('.content').load("index.html #header");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you'd want to try the `.get` method:

```
$.get("index2.html", function( my_var ) {
    var title =  $(my_var).filter('title').text();
    //title contains the title of index2.html
});
```

Just a note that this will only work within the same domain. If you use 'get' to call an external domain you don't control you'll get a CORS error.

Also, this doesn't seem like the most optimal way of doing this as you're basically loading another HTML page.  Not sure what your performance goals are but I might think of another way to retrieve the title.

Comment: Thank you! `var title =  $(my_var).filter('title').text();` didn't return anything but the $.get method works. Since it returns an XML document I can use `var title = my_var.title` to access the title. I don't have any performance goals. I just need to display this information for a small utility locally.

Comment: I think that it is better to use jQuery.parseHTML() here because it does not parse script by default. So end result will be ```$.get("index2.html", function( my_var ) {
    var title =  $('<div />').append($.parseHTML(my_var)).find('title').text();
    //title contains the title of index2.html
});```